# TransformBroadcaster as member of ROS2 Node

Tags: ros2, ros-bouncy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is the proper way to create a `tf2_ros::TransformBroadcaster` inside a `rclcpp::Node`?

I am trying to create a `TransformBroadcaster` as a member of a ROS2 node, i.e. constructing from `this`.
So far, I am constructing the ROS2 node member `tf_broadcaster` from a shared pointer to `this`:

```
MyNode::MyNode() : Node("my_node", "node_namespace", true) {
    // in header: std::unique_ptr<tf2_ros::TransformBroadcaster> tf_broadcaster;
    tf_broadcaster = std::make_unique<tf2_ros::TransformBroadcaster>(rclcpp::Node::SharedPtr(this));
}
```

This seems to work in general, e.g. I can publish my transforms. However, I get a double free corruption error when the node is deconstructed, because the node is deconstructed a second time when `shared_ptr` goes out of scope.

Neither `this->shared_from_this()` (error at construction: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_weak_ptr') nor `std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Node>(this)` (error at deconstruction: free(): invalid pointer) allow me to create a shared pointer of this.

Wouldn't it be easier, if the `rclcpp::Node` would inherit the transformer methods from a `TransformBroadcaster` class instead of instantiating it manually? E.g. `class MyNode : public rclcpp::Node, tf2_ros::TransformBroadcaster {}` and then just call `this->sendTransform(tf);`.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/304033/transformbroadcaster-as-member-of-ros2-node/) by [Christian Rauch](https://answers.ros.org/users/28941/christian-rauch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 214 on 2018-09-23

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2018-12-03**:
I had a TransformBroadcaster member variable that couldn't be constructed from shared_from_this at container class construction time, so I made it a shared ptr and initialized that later, which appeared to function but ctrl-c wouldn't kill the node properly (two ctrl-c in a row would work)

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2018-12-03**:
weak_ptr would break the cyclical shared_ptr there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A workaround would be to simply create the publisher for `tf2_msgs::msg::TFMessage` on `"/tf"` manually like this:

```
#include <tf2_msgs/msg/tf_message.hpp>
...
rclcpp::Publisher<tf2_msgs::msg::TFMessage>::SharedPtr pub_tf;
...
rmw_qos_profile_t tf_qos_profile = rmw_qos_profile_default;
tf_qos_profile.depth = 100;
pub_tf = this->create_publisher<tf2_msgs::msg::TFMessage>("/tf", tf_qos_profile);
tf2_msgs::msg::TFMessage tfs;
geometry_msgs::msg::TransformStamped tf;
// set tf.transform
tfs.transforms.push_back(tf);
// optionally add multiple TransformStamped to tfs.transforms
pub_tf->publish(tfs);
```

For now, the implementation of [TransformBroadcaster](https://github.com/ros2/geometry2/blob/ros2/tf2_ros/src/transform_broadcaster.cpp) is basically doing the same.

Edit:
At least with `foxy`, it is possible to initialise the `TransformBroadcaster` as intended:

```
class MultiWiiNode : public rclcpp::Node {
  tf2_ros::TransformBroadcaster tf_broadcaster;
}

MyNode::MyNode() : Node("my_node"), tf_broadcaster(this) { }
```

---

Originally posted by [Christian Rauch](https://answers.ros.org/users/28941/christian-rauch/) with karma: 214 on 2018-09-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2018-12-03**:
I had strange behavior in bouncy with StaticTransformBroadcaster (including problems kill the node with ctrl-c and 'invalid start byte' messages from launch.LaunchService), switched to TFMessage publication and now am avoiding those issues.